# Explanation of Cantor's diagonal argument?

Tags: set-theory

I struggled to understand the [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument), but I have some problems comprehending the following:

> By construction, $s$ differs from each $s_n$, since their $n^{th}$ digits differ (highlighted in the example). **Hence, $s$ cannot occur in the enumeration.**

Can someone explain why the built sequence $s$ cannot occur in the enumeration? I can imagine it somehow recursively that if we add it to $s_n$, we can pick another sequence with the same construction pattern and we can repeat these steps forever. However, I want to know if this is sufficient as a proof or there is some kind of other explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually more trivial.

1. Suppose that $s$ occurs in the enumeration.
2. Then it occurs at some specific index. Let's call this index $n$. This means that $s = s_n$.
3. But this is impossible, because $s$ and $s_n$ differ in the $n$th digit.